# Issues running PLY Python

Tags: python, ply

I am having issues running PLY in python. I have already installed PLY by downloading the install file online and running it from command prompt. The installation was successful. However, I keep getting the error that "no module named ply". I have put the code below:

VS_Code keeps putting squiggly lines under the ply and ply.yacc part of the import statement.

```
from ply import lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

tokens = (
   
    'MINUS',
    'TIMES',
    'DIV',
    'LPAREN',
    'RPAREN',
    'NUMBER',
)

t_ignore = ' \t'
t_MINUS   = r'-'
t_TIMES   = r'\*'
t_DIV     = r'/'
t_LPAREN  = r'\('
t_RPAREN  = r'\)'

def t_NUMBER( t ) :
    r'[0-9]+'
    t.value = int( t.value )
    return t

def t_newline( t ):
  r'\n+'
  t.lexer.lineno += len( t.value )

def t_error( t ):
  print("Invalid Token:",t.value[0])
  t.lexer.skip( 1 )

lexer = lex.lex()

precedence = (
    ( 'nonassoc', 'UMINUS' ),
    ( 'left', 'TIMES', 'DIV' ),
    ( 'left', 'MINUS' )
)


def p_sub( p ) :
    'expr : expr MINUS expr'
    p[0] = p[1] - p[3]

def p_expr2uminus( p ) :
    'expr : MINUS expr %prec UMINUS'
    p[0] = - p[2]

def p_mult_div( p ) :
    '''expr : expr TIMES expr
            | expr DIV expr'''

    if p[2] == '*' :
        p[0] = p[1] * p[3]
    else :
        if p[3] == 0 :
            print("Can't divide by 0")
            raise ZeroDivisionError('integer division by 0')
        p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

def p_expr2NUM( p ) :
    'expr : NUMBER'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_parens( p ) :
    'expr : LPAREN expr RPAREN'
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_error( p ):
    print("Syntax error in input!")

parser = yacc.yacc()

res = parser.parse("5-8*6-2") # the input  
##res = parser.parse("3+5*8/2") # the input  
print(res)
```

Comment: What "install file"? You can "install" Ply by downloading two Python files from [the github repository](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply#how-to-install-and-use) and putting them in the same directory as your parser.

Comment: @rici: They may be referencing the install at https://pypi.org/project/ply/

Comment: @sean: could be, but the description "I downloaded the install file and ran it" doesn't seem consistent with using pypi, which would normally involve using `pip`, no? That's why I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I'd lay odds that what's happened is that you don't have the "ply" folder in the folder where you have your language source file and you haven't added the location of ply to your sys.path. That will lead to the exact behavior you're indicating with the squiggly line. I suspect you'll also see an "Import "ply" could not be resolved" message in your Problems window.